# maven-war-plugin overlay removes /META-INF/context.xml

Tags: java, maven, war, maven-war-plugin

There are 3 maven projects:

- my-overlay (its a blueprint-war for an overlay only containing the context.xml)
- my-base (its a pom to use in the  scope of real war)
- my-webapp (the final project to use in production as a child-project of the my-base)

I have the my-overlay as a maven project packed as war:

```
+ my-overlay
  + src
    + main
      + webapp
        + META-INF
          + context.xml
        + hello.jpg
  + pom.xml
```

The final my-overlay.war contains the `/META-INF/context.xml` and the `/hello.jpg`.

Now i have another project

```
+ my-base
  + pom.xml
```

having this xml in the `pom.xml`:

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.6</version>
      <configuration>
        <overlays>
          <overlay>
            <id>my-overlay</id>
            <excludes /> <!-- remove the exlude of /META-INF/ -->
          </overlay>
          <overlay></overlay>
        </overlays>
      </...>
```

And i have a third maven-project:

```
+ my-webapp
  + main
    + webapp
      + index.jsp
  + pom.xml
```

Having this in the `pom.xml`:

```
<parent> ... my-base ...</parent>
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

So if i build the `my-webapp` project using `mvn install`, the overlay support the `hello.jpg` but not the `context.xml`. But i removed the default-exclude in the overlay.

What to do to let the overlay support the `META-INF/context.xml`?

**By the way**: Suprisingly the `my-webapp/target/war/work/mygroup/my-overlay/META-INF/context.xml` exists!

Comment: try with <include file="META-INF/context.xml" />

Comment: close because unclear, what is unclear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blocker-Bug Confirmed, prepared for 3.0.0

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MWAR-367